# How to determine the number of node in hidden layer in a BP network when there are dummy variables

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, backpropagation

There is a general formula for calculating the number of nodes in the hidden layer in the BP neural network.

> h=√(m+n)+a

There is such a neural network now.
There are three inputs: occupation, age, gender
And an output: salary

According to the formula, the number of nodes in the hidden layer should be 2+a. That is 3-12 (a usually 1-10).

But job should be seen as a group of dummy variables, assuming there are 50 different jobs. Then the number of dummy variables is 49.
Are the dummy variables counted as input?
If counted, the number of input values is 49+2=51
It is more appropriate to set the number of nodes in the hidden layer at 8-17.
How to choose?(Modified)

Comment: Have never heard of such a rule, and I highly doubt that anything like this is ever used in practice. Care to share a reference?

Comment: My expression here is wrong. It is correct to change "the number of hidden layers" to "the number of nodes in the hidden layer".

Comment: @desertnaut Now these formulas only can be find in my notes. Rules are vary. n is inputs, m is outputs, h is hidden nodes. Here is 6 rules on my notes ---1. Komogorov. _h=2n+1_ ---2. _m<sigma(n,i=0)c[h,i]_ ---3. _h=n-1_ ---4. _h=log2n_ ---5. _h=√(m+n)+a_ ---6. _h=√(0.43mn+2.54m+0.77n+0.35+0.51m^2+0.12n^2)_ no very big difference to use some of them to get the number of nodes in hidden layer. The third rule is for less iteration. And all of them are base on input and output numbers. That's why I ask this question.